# Package Compilation fails when package name contain a "dot" and Rcpp function

Tags: r, g++, rcpp

I am building a new package:

- The package name contains a dot: for example *my.package*
- The package exports one Rcpp function: for example *rcppfunction*

When  I build the package using `Rcmd INSTALL`, `compileAttributes` is used behind the scene to automatically generate exported function,

```
RcppExport SEXP my.package_rcppfunction(...)
```

and I get a compilation error due to the dot in the exported name:

```
RcppExports.cpp:10:19: error: expected initializer before '.' token
```

As a workaround , I can change the package name to remove the dot from it , but I want better solution and to understand how the symbols are exported. So my question is:

1. How can I parametrize the generated code to replace dot by a "_" for example (Maybe by giving some parameters to the export attribute) .
2. Or How to change the g++ call to force it to compile such dotted symbols..

I don't know if this can help , but here my g++ call:

```
g++ -m32 -I"PATH_TO_R/R-30~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG    -
I"PATH_To_R/3.0/Rcpp/include" -
I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/include"     
-O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do that -- the dot simply isn't allowed in a C or C++ function name:

Ie for

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int foo.bar(int x) {
    return(2*x);
}

int main(void) {
    foo.bar(21);
    exit(0);
}
```

we get

```
edd@max:/tmp$ gcc -c foo.c
foo.c:4: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘.’ token
foo.c: In function ‘main’:
foo.c:9: error: ‘foo’ undeclared (first use in this function)
foo.c:9: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
foo.c:9: error: for each function it appears in.)
edd@max:/tmp$
```

and

```
edd@max:/tmp$ g++ -c foo.c
foo.c:4: error: expected initializer before ‘.’ token
foo.c: In function ‘int main()’:
foo.c:9: error: ‘foo’ was not declared in this scope
edd@max:/tmp$
```

In C++,  `foo.bar()` is calling the member function `bar()` of object `foo`.

Comment: Thanks dirk. I will change the package name.

Comment: Or you could keep the name, not use Rcpp Attributes and write your function (interfaces) by hand :)  Just kidding -- a name without an underscore would indeed avoid the issue here.

Comment: :).I guess you mean without "dots" not underscore.  I thought that `compileAttributes` can do some checks before generating the name. Is it difficult to enhance it?

Comment: Yep. And a dot is so anticlimatic that I already mentally converted to an underscore :)

Comment: :) but sometimes it is natural to have it in a package name.

Comment: This is a bug in Rcpp since dots are allowed in R package names :(

Comment: It's an intersection of C++ not allowing a dot in a function name, and Rcpp Attributes placing the package name into a _generated_ function name.  As I said, you could always do the interface by hand.